# Django - context must be a dict rather than ReturnList

Tags: django

I am working on a django project and I have a `Post` Model, which has this view:

```
class PostListApiView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['user','title','content']
```

I use this view to create new posts:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PostCreateView(APIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostCreateSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    template_name = 'post_form.html'

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer=PostCreateSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer':serializer})

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PostCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer':serializer})
        serializer.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

---

I want to consolidate both views into one view,

```
class PostListApiView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['user','title','content']
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'post_form.html'
```

but when I try to add the `TemplateHTMLRenderer` to the `ListCreateAPIView`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 167, in render
    return template.render(context, request=request)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 59, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 270, in make_context
    raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)

Exception Type: TypeError at /posts/
Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than ReturnList.
```

---

Can I use `TemplateHTMLRenderer` to render a queryset and a form on a template, if not - how can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using DRF if you just want to render a template ???

Comment: I use DRF all over my app, I have just one django-only view to be honest. The data is already serialized and both form and listcreate view work, so why don't consolidate both views into one template?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and started debugging DRF to try to figure it out. It would seem that there is some sort of problem among DRF's serializers, TemplateHTMLRenderer and Django's templates renderer.

In my case, I'm trying to use ListCreateAPIView to have default get and create behavior. I wanted to have both json and html responses, so tried this code:

```
class TransactionsController(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'transactions/index.html'
```

which, when trying to access the transactions list and ins spite of following DRF documentation returns:

[image]

It would seem that django\template\context.py expects a dict, but DRF serializers returns a ReturnList **(at least when no data is retrieved from database)**. This empty ReturnList is handled by TemplateHTMLRenderer which in turn calls django renderers, which throw the exception.

My quick fix for the moment is:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer

from applications.core.models.transaction import Transaction, TransactionSerializer


class TransactionsTemplateHTMLRender(TemplateHTMLRenderer):
    def get_template_context(self, data, renderer_context):
        data = super().get_template_context(data, renderer_context)
        if not data:
            return {}
        else:
            return data


class TransactionsController(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TransactionsTemplateHTMLRender]
    template_name = 'transactions/index.html'
```

This checks the data DRF's serializer returns, and if it is empty, then a dict is returned (instead of the default ReturnList). It works, but now We've got to see what happens when actual data is retrieved from database.

And I guess it would be a good idea to report this on DRF github.